# Confused with gazebo plugin path

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So, when I use the plugin libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so, I was able to successfully get the images I want. However, I am trying to locate the path for libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so, so I looked to setup.sh and found that the GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH is:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-9/plugins

But when I go into this path, I can't find libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so. Are there any other place that libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so is located?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25591/confused-with-gazebo-plugin-path/) by [kolohe113](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28855/kolohe113/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Some of the paths could be defined in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too. If you have installed ROS from Debian packages these plugins are in `/opt/ros/<rosdistro>/` or in your install directory if you installed ROS from sources. A command to find the library could be:

```
du -a /opt/ros/<rosdistro> | grep libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so
```

or

```
du -a <path to your workspace> | grep libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so
```

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kolohe113](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28855/kolohe113/) on 2020-08-01**:
Found it on /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libgazebo_ros_multicamera.so
Thank you!